# "multiple target patterns" Makefile error

Tags: makefile

My makefile fails with error:

```
Makefile:34: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
```

What does it really mean, how can I fix this?

([GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html), written by Captain Obvious, isn't helping).

---

Found it. I had rule in form:

```
$(FOO): bar
```

where `FOO` was set from shell command that polluted it with error message that contained a colon.

Comment: does http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21119863 or http://sourceware.org/ml/crossgcc/2009-07/msg00006.html help?

Comment: A swift google reveals http://groups.google.com/group/gnu.utils.help/browse_frm/thread/d7eeff06e2b8394/1c932a7ea7664ade?lnk=st&q=%22multiple+target+patterns%22&rnum=7#1c932a7ea7664ade

Comment: These answers are just paraphrases of "you've got multiple target patterns". Well, I think I don't. How can I check it? What can trigger it? What precautions are needed to prevent this problem?

Comment: Everything was working one minute and then my script sneezed out a (semi)colon... heheh. Sweated it out trying to find the problem for at least 3 hours before I found your and @mcr 's answer. You just saved me a bucketful of sweat!!

Comment: The true root cause of this problem is GNU Make being a horrible piece of dung that should have died decades ago.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I had it on the Makefile

```
MAPS+=reverse/db.901:550:2001.ip6.arpa 
lastserial:  ${MAPS}
    ./updateser ${MAPS}
```

It's because of the `:` in the file name.
I solved this with

```
                      -------- notice
                     /    /
                    v    v
MAPS+=reverse/db.901\:550\:2001.ip6.arpa
lastserial:  ${MAPS}
    ./updateser ${MAPS}
```

Comment: i have the same problem, but i don't understand your answer, will you elaborate this further for me,

Comment: @PirFahimShah The answer is stating that the colons in the filename (db.901:550:2001.ip6.arpa) need to be escaped. mcr is escaping the colons by putting a backslash before them. That way, make does not interpret the colons as a special symbol.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. I had some old windows path with colon in it (`C:/Qt/5.8/mingw53_32/bin/rcc.exe`) in one of Makefile rules. Remove those autogenerated makefiles if you are building on Linux machine

Comment: windows make switched to wsl (ubuntu) and got this error, `make clean` followed by `make` solved it. The erroneous line was `_build/nrf52840_xxaa/app_mpu.c.o: ../../../app_mpu.c \ `

Answer (score 36):

Besides having to escape colons as in the original answer, I have found if the indentation is off you could potentially get the same problem.  In one makefile, I had to replace spaces with a tab and that allowed me to get past the error.

Comment: GNU make may also report "No Rule for Target" in this case.

Answer (score 4):

I just want to add, if you get this error because you are using Cygwin make and
auto-generated files, you can fix it with the following sed,

```sh
sed -e 's@\\\([^ ]\)@/\1@g' -e 's@[cC]:@/cygdrive/c@' -i filename.d
```

You may need to add more characters than just space to the escape list in the
first substitution but you get the idea. The concept here is that /cygdrive/c is
an alias for c: that cygwin's make will recognize.

And may as well throw in

```sh
-e 's@^ \+@\t@'
```

just in case you did start with spaces on accident (although I /think/ this will
usually be a "missing separator" error).

Answer (score 4):

I met with the same error. 
After struggling, I found that it was due to "Space" in the folder name.

For example :

Earlier My folder name was :
 **"Qt Projects"**

Later I changed it to :
**"QtProjects"**

and my issue was resolved.

Its very simple but sometimes a major issue.

Answer (score 4):

My IDE left a mix of spaces and tabs in my Makefile.

Setting my Makefile to use only tabs fixed this error for me.

Comment: This has got me an embarassing number of times. I'm aware Make uses tabs for indentation, but my IDE is set to autoconvert tabs to spaces. Gotta keep remembering to convert them back to tabs whenever I'm working on Makefiles.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error and my issue was an extra whitespace and a backslash at the end of listing source files:

```
SRCS := ft_striteri.c \
        ft_putchar_fd.c \
        ft_putstr_fd.c \
        ft_putendl_fd.c \
        ft_putnbr_fd.c \
BONUS_SRCS :=   ft_lstadd_back.c \
                ft_lstadd_front.c \
                ft_lstlast.c \
                ft_lstnew.c \
                ft_lstsize.c
```

The correct version that works looks like this:

```
SRCS := ft_striteri.c \
        ft_putchar_fd.c \
        ft_putstr_fd.c \
        ft_putendl_fd.c \
        ft_putnbr_fd.c
BONUS_SRCS :=   ft_lstadd_back.c \
                ft_lstadd_front.c \
                ft_lstlast.c \
                ft_lstnew.c \
                ft_lstsize.c
```

Comment: I dont think the whitespace was the issue here. With the errant \ you were actually including `BONUS_SRCS :=` in SRCS. Not the definition, but the the literal text. Then, as others pointed out, you would receive this error because of the `:` in the rules using this "source file"

Answer (score 1):

Because Make doesn't do quoting *remotely* properly this can also happen if you pass in filenames that contain characters it doesn't like (spaces or `:`) and then you expand them. For example:

```
LINKER_SCRIPT := link.ld

exe: foo.cpp $(LINKER_SCRIPT)
    gcc blah blah blah
```

If you now run

```
make LINKER_SCRIPT=link:0.ld
```

Make will stupidly expand it to this:

```
exe: foo.cpp link:0.ld
    gcc blah blah blah
```

And then get confused about the `:` in the filename.

As far as I can tell there's no sane way to solve this problem other than *stop using Make*.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem (colons in the target name) because I had `-n` in my `GREP_OPTIONS` environment variable. Apparently, this caused `configure` to generate the `Makefile` incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error (within the Eclipse-based STM32CubeIDE on Windows).

After double-clicking on the "multiple target patterns" error it showed a path to a `.ld` file. It turns out to be another "illegal character" problem. The offending character was the (wait for it): **=**

Heuristic of the week: use only [a..z] in your paths, as there are bound to be other illegal characters </vomit>.

The [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html) doesn't explicitly document this.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and it was because I used explorer to copy/paste a directory into Windows Subsystem For Linux.  Owner of all the files was `root`, but my WSL user was `art`.  When I tried moving or modifying any files in the directory as user `art` I got permission denied.

I gave it a `sudo chown -R <my user name> <path to my containing folder>` to change the file owner to myself and it built after that.