# Failed to install Jekyll using Gem in Ruby: redcarpet-3.2.0 Makefile:238 error: Multiple target patterns

Tags: ruby, makefile, rubygems, installation, jekyll

I'm failing to install Jekyll using gem in Ruby. Here's the output messages:

```
D:\Ruby21\bin>gem install jekyll
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    D:/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean
Makefile:238: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

make "DESTDIR="
Makefile:238: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in D:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redcarpet-3.2.0 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/redcarpet-3.2.0/gem_make.out

D:\Ruby21\bin>
```

[Unlike the other issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040052/failing-to-install-jekyll-gem-native-extension-on-windows-with-multiple-target), where the error breaks in the Makefile on line 222, mine breaks in the Makefile on line 238.

I can tell it has nothing to do with spaces in my installation path (since I installed Ruby in the root of my D drive). But anything from there is beyond my scope.

I'm using Windows Vista x86. I have installed Ruby 2.1.0 stable.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: If you are downvoting, please provide feedback, in order for me to be a better Stack Overflow member. Any feedback is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I didn't solve the problem, but rather I used a workaround.

I installed Cygwin-x86 on my laptop, then installed Ruby and Rubygem, finally installed Jekyll and managed to go past the redcarpet-v3.2.0 build error.

To install Jekyll in Cygwin:

1. Run cygwin-setup.exe.
2. Install appropriate packages: Ruby, rubygem, make, gcc, git, libxslt, libxml2. Some more packages may be required [here](http://matt.scharley.me/2012/03/10/windows-cygwin-and-jekyll.html).
3. Install jekyll using `gem install jekyll`. Wait.
4. Type in command: `vim ~/.bashrc`
5. Scroll to the end and add `export PATH=$PATH:".gem/ruby/gems/jekyll-2.4.0/bin"`

That's how the Jekyll is installed on Cygwin.

Later on, you may need the following:

- Subversion
- bzip2
- [apt-cyg](https://code.google.com/p/apt-cyg/)
- patch
- curl
- rvm
- jemoji
- jekyll-sitemap

And have to do a lot of `~/.bashrc` editing, calling `source $HOME/path/to/rvm` and PATH fixing.