# fatal error: opencv/cvtypes.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I am on a ubuntu 12.04 machine, with opencv 2.4.1 and gcc version 4.6.3. I have an old opencv code that I have to compile. It includes the `opencv/cvtypes.h`header file, which isn't included in this version of opencv installation. My `/usr/local/include/opencv` has only these header files:

- cvaux.h
- cv.h
- cvwimage.h
- cxcore.hpp
- cxmisc.h
- ml.h
- cvaux.hpp
- cv.hpp
- cxcore.h
- cxeigen.hpp
- highgui.h

I noticed on some threads [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401976/very-simple-application-fails-with-multiple-target-patterns-from-eclipse) and [[2]](http://finaleanalyst.blogspot.in/2011/04/how-to-check-if-opencv-is-properly.html) (dealing with opencv installation; older versions) that their `/usr/local/include/opencv` folder contained 20-21 header files. Which library has `cvtypes.h` been clubbed into? Is there a quick way of knowing such a thing, in general, without actually looking at the source code?

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to just replace with a script or your IDE any occurrence of `cvtypes.h` by the `.h` headers.

As far as I can remember, the information that was in `cvtypes.h` is in `cxcore.h`. `.hpp` header files are for the old C++ API and should be avoided.

Comment: did you mean `cxcore.h` instead of `cvcore.h`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I fixed my answer.