# src/Window.d:1: *** multiple target patterns. Stop

Tags: c++, eclipse

My name is Arillious. I am new to programming and have been learning the C++ syntax for about a year now. Eclipse is my first experience with extensive use of an IDE... its like learning a syntax all over again. however, I've been following others trial and tribulations finding some success here and there. I've written some code, the ever so simple hello world because I want to see the compiler in action.

Before I continue here is some info about my setup:

E:\cygwind64 //Location of my cigwin installation.

E:\Eclipse //Location of my Eclipse installation.

Here is my issue that has been covered before, but I'm having a hard time following the fix or solutions:

src/Window.d:1: *** multiple target patterns. Stop.

the best solutions I've found are here:

[Very simple application fails with "multiple target patterns" from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401976/very-simple-application-fails-with-multiple-target-patterns-from-eclipse)

but i don't know how to get any of the suggestions to work as I've have tried them
I'm at my whits end.

thank you if you have the time and patience.

Arillious

Comment: added info. im on a windows 7 pc.

Answer (score 1):

For individuals like my self, who search every where for their keys and makes a fuss about it only to find them on the speaker box, this is where I found the fix:

http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html

scroll down to:

"5.  Tips & Tricks"

and number "6" of the category "5.1  C/C++ Software Development Using GCC" you will find:

***Error "multiple target patterns": There is a problem with GNU make (at $Cygwin\bin\make.exe). Replaced by this copy @ http://www.cmake.org/files/cygwin/make.exe.***

Apologies if I have wasted anyone's time. I genuinely have been searching for solutions with out any luck (yes longer than five minutes or a day).

In any case everyone has a particular stance. I may not always be the sharpest tool, but for those who may or even may not align with my sentiments I've shared a solution to a personal problem. Hope someones else can find it useful.

Best