# Eclipse with CDT not compiling at all

Tags: c++, eclipse, cygwin

I have been trying out using Eclipse CDT for a course I am taking.
 Previously I have been using Visual Studio Express but since that requires me to be online and I have to use the IDE+compiler offline, I switched to Eclipse + Cygwin GCC.

Now everything was working prefectly, until I got an error about file paths in my make file. After reading some of the posts online, the issue seemed to be that Cygwin's make does not resolve absolute Windows file paths because of the ':' symbol and confuses it with a new target definition. The proposed fix was to download a fixed make file. I diligently did so and the programs would compile fine.

But after I went into the first debug session, everything froze. I aborted eclipse and tried a clean build but now the compilation wont happen AT ALL, which is very weird for me.

I can't find a post for a similar problem so I am really stuck now. I was currently working the assumption that my CDT may be corrupt or something so I downloaded Eclipse Luna just today and tried building using that, but no joy. Even a fresh project in a new workspace wont compile.

Appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: Could you append both, the original and the "fixed", makefiles to your question?

Comment: Eclipse is an IDE, not a compiler. Did you try to compile in a terminal?

Comment: Theolodis: Please pardon my illiteracy about Stack Overflow... Do I attach the make executables? If so, how do I do that? I dont see an attach option in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like an issue with the new make (v3.80). upgating it to v4.08 fixed the issue of not building.

Version 4.08 however does not fix the Windows file paths not being recognized properly and treated as a target definition. I am still getting the multiple target patterns. stop error.

EDIT: Found this on Stack overflow to solve the issue... should have searched better previously.

[Very simple application fails with "multiple target patterns" from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401976/very-simple-application-fails-with-multiple-target-patterns-from-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try redownloading Eclipse? Sometimes Eclipse gets a fatal error glitch that makes it unable to compile anything. I've had this problem before, the only way i was able to fix it was to uninstall and re download the latest version. If this doesnt work, try switching to Bloodshed Dev C++ or codeblocks.

Comment: Yep Downloaded Eclipse Luna just now. tried building with that too...

Now I am thinking its a problem with my make, gcc or g++ in cygwin.

Comment: Maybe. Id recommend Downloading Bloodshed, and then trying Eclipse again. Some times the patch for one software will solve for the other issues

Comment: it could also be that a previous program you ran was never killed, preventing further compiling. check task manager

Comment: Did a restart so no chances of that, I believe.

Comment: I am updating make from cygwin setup  right now, will run using command line and test, like Basile suggested.