# Multiple target patterns?

Tags: c, cygwin

I'm trying to compile a c file where I included a driver for Mongo database. I can compile it successfully from Cygwin but when I turn to Netbeans I get this. I should mention that this happened only after adding "-std=c99" in Additional options for C compiler.

UPDATE:
Successfully compiled it from Netbeans. But the "-std=c99" is driving me mad. If I have it it says (after every compilation if I don't delete the obj files):

```
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o.d:1: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
```

UPDATE:
The content of main.o.d is:

```
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o: main.c \
 c:/mongodb-driver/src/mongo.h c:/mongodb-driver/src/bson.h \
 c:/mongodb-driver/src/platform.h

c:/mongodb-driver/src/mongo.h:

c:/mongodb-driver/src/bson.h:

c:/mongodb-driver/src/platform.h:
```

Comment: So what is in line 1 of `main.o.d`? - Related: [“multiple target patterns” Makefile error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2100448/269126)

Comment: @Lumi build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o: main.c \

Comment: And on the next line? A trailing backslash in a Makefile indicates line continuation. Please update your post to include all relevant details, that's better than serving it piecewise in the comment lines.

Comment: @Lumi added the entire content of the main.o.d file

Comment: There you go, the colons are your problem. The answer given by @fayyazkl is correct, go upvote and accept it.

Comment: @Lumi how can I mount it to not have to edit it everytime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from an existing answer since you might have the same issue

"I've seen this problem before using Cygwin--basically, make sees the : in the path and thinks it is another target definition, hence the error.

If you are working from a Cygwin installation, you might try replacing the c:/ with /cygdrive/c/. If not, you might try using relative paths or using a network mount and see if that fixes it".

[application fails with multiple targets from eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401976/very-simple-application-fails-with-multiple-target-patterns-from-eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

From your comment:

> @Lumi how can I mount it to not have to edit it everytime?

Fix the script that generates `main.o.d` (and probably lots of other `.d` files) to write relative paths, or absolute paths that Cygwin's `make` understands.

Alternatively, consider whether using [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) instead of Cygwin is an option for you. (But I have the feeling that you'll run into more issues when following that road.)

Ultimately, to cope with Makefiles, you need to read up on how Make works. [GNU Make has a comprehensive manual.](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) I found [these tips](http://www.working-software.com/node/19) very useful. The best for you, at this stage, would probably be [Scott Duckworth's Make tutorial](http://www.cs.clemson.edu/~duckwos/make/).

Comment: thanks, MinGW is not an option. I have it installed but it doesn't come with the UNIX libraries I need.