# Open CV Application execution time error?

Tags: opencv

i am running my Project "DisplayImage",**Open CV** application in eclipse, but i got error in **DisplayImage.d** under Debug Folder the error is :

```
  make: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
```

and my code is :

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
using namespace cv;

 int main( int argc, char** argv )
 {
  Mat image;
  image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

 if( argc != 2 || !image.data )
   {
     printf( "No image data \n" );
     return -1;
   }

   namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
   imshow( "Display Image", image );

   waitKey(0);

   return 0;
 }
```

i have successfuly include lib and open cv in project,but i got this error when i try to runs the project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100448/multiple-target-patterns-makefile-error did u see this?

Comment: @AbhishekThakur, this one is great, but i have't found the code in a maekfile, where the man have shown in his answer code,