# Makefile : Multiple target patterns. Stop

Tags: makefile

I am on Windows environment using Cygwin shell to build a program.

I passed through rest other commands successfully but while I try to run **make** on my Makefile, it throws this error :

> Makefile:124: Multiple target patterns, Stop.

This is line where error is generating.

> **$(TARGETPATH)/.o: $(DEPENDANCIES)   $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUG_FLAGS) $(SOURCES)**

The reason why I am confused is I have other commands in the same makefile that runs successfully with the make command, only this at line 124 in makefile is what is generating the error.

I tried finding solutions but none helped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's in your $(TARGETPATH)? And $(DEPENDANCIES)? Maybe one of them contains a colon?

Comment: The **$(TARGETPATH)=.**  and  **$(DEPENDANCIES)=$(TARGETNAME).c                     \ Makefile \
  $(INCLUDEPATH)/$(TARGETNAME).h \
  $(STD_EVENT) \
  config.h utils.h oppgtrigger_db.h\
  oppgtrigger_yacc.y oppgtrigger_lex.l**                              **TARGETNAME=oppgtrigger** and **STD_EVENT= ../../../src/std_event.h** and  **

Comment: possible duplicate of ["multiple target patterns" Makefile error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100448/multiple-target-patterns-makefile-error)