# Make fails due to multiple target patterns, when compiling android msm kernel for nexus 6p

Tags: android, makefile, kernel

I think the source of the problem is that head-y isn't set anywhere, but I don't know what to do for that.

Commands I used to compile

```
$ export ARCH=arm64
$ export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-android-
$ cd msm-angler
$ make msm_defconfig
$ make
```

I didn't use the git-checkout command because i just downloaded the tar.gz file from the google git repos

Some warning come up when using the make msm_defconfig command.

```
arch/arm64/configs/msm_defconfig:431:
warning: override: reassigning to symbol LEDS_TRIGGERS
warning: (SND_SOC_APQ8084 && SND_SOC_MSM8X16 && SND_SOC_MSM8994) selects SND_SOC_CPE which has unmet direct dependencies (SOUND && !M68K && !UML && SND && SND_SOC && SND_SOC_WCD_CPE)
warning: (SND_SOC_QDSP6V2) selects SND_SOC_MSM_QDSP6V2_INTF which has unmet direct dependencies (SOUND && !M68K && !UML && SND && SND_SOC && MSM_QDSP6_APRV2)
warning: (ARCH_MSM) selects DEVFREQ_GOV_MSM_BW_HWMON which has unmet direct dependencies (PM_DEVFREQ && (ARCH_MSM_KRAIT || ARCH_MSM_BIMC_BWMON))
warning: (SND_SOC_QDSP6V2) selects SND_SOC_MSM_QDSP6V2_INTF which has unmet direct dependencies (SOUND && !M68K && !UML && SND && SND_SOC && MSM_QDSP6_APRV2)
warning: (SND_SOC_APQ8084 && SND_SOC_MSM8X16 && SND_SOC_MSM8994) selects SND_SOC_CPE which has unmet direct dependencies (SOUND && !M68K && !UML && SND && SND_SOC && SND_SOC_WCD_CPE)
warning: (ARCH_MSM) selects DEVFREQ_GOV_MSM_BW_HWMON which has unmet direct dependencies (PM_DEVFREQ && (ARCH_MSM_KRAIT || ARCH_MSM_BIMC_BWMON))
#
# configuration written to .config
#
```

This is the error that comes up when running make

```
Makefile:796: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
```

Here is line 796

```
vmlinux: scripts/link-vmlinux.sh $(vmlinux-deps) FORCE
```

Here is where vmlinux-deps is set (line 788)

```
vmlinux-deps := $(KBUILD_LDS) $(KBUILD_VMLINUX_INIT) $(KBUILD_VMLINUX_MAIN)
```

Here is where KBUILD_LDS, KBUILD_VMLINUX_INIT, and KBUILD_VMLINUX_MAIN are set (lines 781-783)

```
export KBUILD_VMLIUX_INIT := $(head-y) $(init-y)
export KBUILD_VMLINUX_MAIN := $(core-y) $(libs-y) $(drivers-y) $(net-y)
export KBUILD_LDS          := arch/$(SRCARCH)/kernel/vmlinux.lds
```

Here is where all the *-y stuff is set (except for head-y) (Lines 525-529)

```
init-y          := init/
drivers-y       := drivers/ sound/ firmware/
net-y           := net/
libs-y          := lib/
core-y          := usr/
```

I can't seem to find anywhere where head-y is set, this is probably the source of the problem, but I don't know what to put for head-y.

Comment: Hi! Did you ever find a solution to this? I am running into this problem as well. If yes, it would be great if you could post an answer to your own question. Thanks!

Comment: Sadly no, sorry

Comment: What is your make version? Is that GNU Make? If not, then simply expanded variables (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors) may not work (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100448/multiple-target-patterns-makefile-error). head-y expands as an empty string if that's not defined. This may cause a compile error if needed somewhere, but probably not a Makefile error. You can try to set that head-y := head/ if that directory exists, if that won't work.