# makefile multiple target patterns. Stop

Tags: java, eclipse, makefile, cmake, gnu

Facing following error in makefile

```
Makefile:54: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
```

Full source code of makefile as below

```
MINGW_HOME ?= C:/mingw
PRODUCTNAME ?= Jitsi
COMPANYNAME ?= jitsi.org
PRODUCTBUILDVERSION ?= 1.0.0.0
PRODUCTBUILDVERSION_COMMA ?= 1,0,0,0
TARGET_BASENAME ?= run
TARGET_DIR ?= ../../../../release/windows/tmp

ifeq ($(wildcard /bin/cygpath.*),/bin/cygpath.exe)
    target.dir := $(shell cygpath --mixed "$(TARGET_DIR)")
    cygwin.target.dir := $(shell cygpath --unix "$(TARGET_DIR)")
else
    target.dir := $(TARGET_DIR)
    cygwin.target.dir := $(TARGET_DIR)
endif

CC = $(MINGW_HOME)/bin/gcc.exe
CPPFLAGS := $(CPPFLAGS) \
    -Wall -Wreturn-type \
    -DPSAPI_VERSION=1 \
    -DWINVER=0x0502 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0502 \
    -I$(target.dir) \
    -I"$(JAVA_HOME)/include" -I"$(JAVA_HOME)/include/win32"
LDFLAGS = -mwindows
LIBS = -ladvapi32 -lpsapi

MACHINE = $(shell $(CC) -dumpmachine)
WINDRES = $(MINGW_HOME)/bin/windres.exe
ifneq ("x$(MACHINE)","x")
ifeq ($(wildcard $(MINGW_HOME)/bin/$(MACHINE)-windres.*),$(MINGW_HOME)/bin/$(MACHINE)-windres.exe)
    WINDRES = $(MINGW_HOME)/bin/$(MACHINE)-windres.exe
endif
endif

$(cygwin.target.dir)/$(TARGET_BASENAME).exe: $(cygwin.target.dir)/config.h registry.c run.c $(cygwin.target.dir)/run.res ../setup/nls.c
    **$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) registry.c run.c $(target.dir)/run.res ../setup/nls.c $(LDFLAGS) -o $(target.dir)/$(TARGET_BASENAME).exe $(LIBS)**
    -$(MINGW_HOME)/$(MACHINE)/bin/strip.exe $(target.dir)/$(TARGET_BASENAME).exe

.PHONY: $(cygwin.target.dir)/config.h

$(cygwin.target.dir)/config.h:
    -rm.exe -f ../../../../resources/install/windows/config.h
    echo #define PRODUCTNAME "$(PRODUCTNAME)" > $(cygwin.target.dir)/config.h
    echo #define COMPANYNAME "$(COMPANYNAME)" >> $(cygwin.target.dir)/config.h
    echo #define PRODUCTBUILDVERSION "$(PRODUCTBUILDVERSION)" >> $(cygwin.target.dir)/config.h
    echo #define PRODUCTBUILDVERSION_COMMA $(PRODUCTBUILDVERSION_COMMA) >> $(cygwin.target.dir)/config.h
    echo #define TARGET_BASENAME "$(TARGET_BASENAME)" >> $(cygwin.target.dir)/config.h
    echo #define TARGET_BASENAME_EXE "$(TARGET_BASENAME).exe" >> $(cygwin.target.dir)/config.h

$(cygwin.target.dir)/run.res: $(cygwin.target.dir)/config.h run.rc
    $(WINDRES) -I../../../../resources/install/windows -I$(target.dir) run.rc -O coff -o $(target.dir)/run.res
```

and the line number 54 is given below.

```
$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) registry.c run.c $(target.dir)/run.res ../setup/nls.c $(LDFLAGS) -o $(target.dir)/$(TARGET_BASENAME).exe $(LIBS)
```

what could be the possible cause for this.

Comment: One of the dependencies to your target may contain `:` which confuses `make`, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3711394/6332023).

Comment: @J.Borgh yes I have checked that answer already but I could not find same with my case.

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct/complete makefile?  It only has 51 lines whereas the error is reported at line 54.

Comment: I didn't add comment lines here, You can match line content which I have given below. I have added a double star to start and end to stand out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually Had a silly mistake instead of Tab space there was spaces which was causing an issue.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. Tab works. But not spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen because I had a `:` in a filename.

Specifically, I had this crap

```
./lib/libwww-perl-5.837/share/man/man3/HTTP::Daemon.3pm
./lib/libwww-perl-5.837/share/man/man3/HTTP::Date.3pm
./lib/libwww-perl-5.837/share/man/man3/HTTP::Headers.3pm
./lib/libwww-perl-5.837/share/man/man3/HTTP::Headers::Util.3pm
./lib/libwww-perl-5.837/share/man/man3/HTTP::Message.3pm
./lib/libwww-perl-5.837/share/man/man3/HTTP::Negotiate.3pm
./lib/libwww-perl-5.837/share/man/man3/HTTP::Request.3pm
./lib/libwww-perl-5.837/share/man/man3/HTTP::Request::Common.3pm
./lib/libwww-perl-5.837/share/man/man3/HTTP::Response.3pm
./lib/libwww-perl-5.837/share/man/man3/HTTP::Status.3pm
./lib/libwww-perl-5.837/share/man/man3/LWP::Authen::Ntlm.3pm
./lib/libwww-perl-5.837/share/man/man3/LWP::ConnCache.3pm
./lib/libwww-perl-5.837/share/man/man3/LWP::Debug.3pm
./lib/libwww-perl-5.837/share/man/man3/LWP::MediaTypes.3pm
./lib/libwww-perl-5.837/share/man/man3/LWP::MemberMixin.3pm
./lib/libwww-perl-5.837/share/man/man3/LWP::Protocol.3pm
./lib/libwww-perl-5.837/share/man/man3/LWP::RobotUA.3pm
./lib/libwww-perl-5.837/share/man/man3/LWP::Simple.3pm
./lib/libwww-perl-5.837/share/man/man3/LWP::UserAgent.3pm
./lib/libwww-perl-5.837/share/man/man3/Net::HTTP.3pm
```